# react native app crash without log in debug mode

Tags: javascript, react-native

i'm using the last version of react and react-native :

```
"react": "16.1.1",
"react-native": "^0.50.3"
```

**Some times my app's crash completely and close without any log in chrome and i don't get the red screen on the phone, i'm in debug mode of course and get usual error or log in chrome console.**

For example with this view, i render the same data. The render 1 work well and don't crash the app. the render 2 work for fews lines thans the app crash

[image]

I get the app crash without any log for other kind of bug too ( missing parameter in props for example ).

Any way to track or solve this ? i don't found local tools for that

Comment: Did you try connecting it to android studio and checking the error logs?

Comment: no never used android studio, i compile with commande "react-native run-android" only. how to do this please ?

Comment: Try running react-native log-android

Comment: i launched the app via "react-native log-android". i got text in the console like `D/ReactNative( 4793): CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle()
D/ReactNative( 4793): ReactInstanceManager.setupReactContext()
D/ReactNative( 4793): CatalystInstanceImpl.initialize()
D/ReactNative( 4793): ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance()`   but nothing when app crash

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I finaly solve this by using `adb logcat`, working for android

`adb logcat com.yourAppName:D *:W`

yourAppName is the one you used in package.json under name field